# Switch button to textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on WPF application , and i want to switch a Button to textBox when i press that button . i tried to hide the button and to change the margin of the textbox when on the code of the click but the margin does not change . 
so what should i do ?

```
private void sh_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t = new TextBox();
    Button b = new Button();
    b = sb;
    t = valeur;
    b.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    t.Margin = new Thickness(2, 2, 4, 2);
    t.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;          
}
```

Comment: These controls are local variables to this function. They are not added to the visual tree. What are you trying to do? Is this your actual code? This code is not going to do anything.

Comment: Valeur and sb are variables  declared on xaml code . when i press the button the textbox become visible i just want to put it on the place of the button

Comment: change b.visibility = visibility.hidden to 
sb.visibility = visibility.collapsed ( to hide the original button )

Comment: already done ! no result :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your methode won't work because you never add the new texbox to the visual tree.
You can get the properties of the Button (content, width, height etc.) because this is the "sender".

Example if you button is in a Grid :

```
private void sh_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            TextBox texbox = new TextBox();
            texbox.Width = button.ActualWidth;
            texbox.Height = button.ActualHeight;
            texbox.Text = button.Content.ToString();
            button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ((Grid)button.Parent).Children.Add(texbox);
            Grid.SetRow(texbox, Grid.GetRow(button));
            Grid.SetColumn(texbox, Grid.GetColumn(button));
        }
    }
```

**Edit :** If you already have the textbox in the XAML you don't need to instancy one more TextBox like in my example. You just have to put visibility to visible.

Comment: this is overly complex, and it's bad practice to be creating controls in the codebehind.

Comment: he was indeed unclear about that, but unless there is an expressed reason to create controls from codebehind, it should be discouraged.

Comment: i used that code but the margin of the textbox didn't change

Answer (score 3):

What you should do is add the TextBox to the XAML, then refer to it directly to show / hide the button and textbox.

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="sh" Click="sh_Click_1"/>
<TextBox x:Name="valeur" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

C#:

```
private void sh_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sh.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    valeur.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;          
}
```

Comment: then refer to them like i did here and it will work fine. you don't need to create a new button and text box in the code behind